# What does the warning in developer mode mean?

Tags: windows, maui

I want to try MAUI but when I press the first time to run in a windows machine. I have to enable the developer mode but I get a warning:

***Turning on developer mode, including installing and running apps from outside the Microsoft Store, could expose your device and personal data to security risks or harm your device.***

That sounds unsafe to me. What does that actually mean?

Comment: A packaged app is normally uploaded to the Store, verified by Microsoft to ensure it doesn't do anything nasty to the user's machine, then provided with a certificate that proves that the app is secure.  That's a chicken-and-egg problem when you develop such an app, you can't get it reviewed when you're still debugging it.  Turning on developer mode allows the uncertified app to run anyway.  But with the risk that a malicious app takes advantage as well.  Pay more attention to where the packaged app came from.

Answer (score 0):

It means you can install unsigned apps from unknown sources.